# Errors in vertical simple form

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, haml, simple-form

I'm using simple_form gem in my Ruby on Rails project with bootstrap. In a vertical form when help-block with error is displayed I have something like this: [image]

How can I fix help-block class in CSS to moved an error name to the bottom of whole line, without increasing the icon?

Here is a piece of my HAML:

```
    .form-group.input-group
      %span.input-group-addon
        %i.fa.fa-lock
      = f.input :password, label: false, placeholder: 'Type password'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by modifying the default wrapper in your simple_form config file.  The way to do this with the default (non-bootstrap) config is to modify the Inputs section default wrapper in `config/initializers/simple_form.rb`, from:

```
b.use :label_input
b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: :hint }
b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: :error }
```

to:

```
b.use :label
b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: :hint }
b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: :error }
b.use :input
```

You can apply the same technique to the bootstrap version of the configuration.

This will make individual checkboxes look a little odd when they have errors, so you will also want to make a version of the wrapper that is a duplicate of the original config and set it up just for use with the `boolean` input type.  For example (again from the default config, not the bootstrap config):

```
config.wrappers :checks, class: :input,
    hint_class: :field_with_hint, error_class: :field_with_errors do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.optional :maxlength
    b.optional :pattern
    b.optional :min_max
    b.optional :readonly

    ## Inputs
    b.use :label_input
    b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: :hint }
    b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: :error }
end
config.wrapper_mappings = { boolean: :checks }
```